# shell running hadoop commands

Tags: shell

i wanted to avoid keep tying all the commands to run simple mapreduce everytime i want to test out mapper and reducer files so i wrote this script and i am new to shell scripting. I want to know if these hadoops commands will run in shell scripting and if the script would need any changes?

```
echo textFile :"$1"
echo mapper : "$2"
echo reducer: "$3"
echo inputDir :"$4"
echo outputDir: "$5"



hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/"$2" # copies mapper.py file from argument to hdfs dir   
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/"$3" # copies reducer.py file from argument to hdfs dir


hdfs dfs -test -d ~/"$5"  #checks to see if hadoop output dir exists
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   hdfs dfs -rm -r ~/"$5"
else
    echo "Output file doesn't exist and will be created when hadoop runs"
fi



hdfs dfs -test -d ~/"$4" #checks to see if hadoop input dir exists
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    hdfs dfs -rm -r ~/"$4"
    echo "Hadoop input dir alread exists deleting it now and creating a new    one..."
    hdfs dfs -mkdir ~/"$4"  # makes an input dir for text file to be put in

else
    echo "Input file doesn't exist will be created now"
    hdfs dfs -mkdir ~/"$4"  # makes an input dir for text file to be put in
fi



 hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/"$1" ~/"$4" # sends textfile from local to hdfs folder

 # runs the hadoop mapreduce program with given parameters
 hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-
 2.6.2.jar -input /home/hduser/"$4"/* -output /home/hduser/"$5" -file
 /home/hduser/"$2" -mapper /home/hduser/"$2" -file
 /home/hduser/"$3" -reducer /home/hduser/"$3"
```

Comment: Use http://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. it will run if proper arguments are passed.